# How can I change the active soldier?

Tags: battlefield-3

I want to start a new soldier that I use solely as an aircraft soldier, but I can't seem to figure out how to actually create one (like you could in Bad Company 2, for example).

Can I even do that in Battlefield 3, and if so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, EA/DICE took this feature out for some reason. The extra slots on the Battlelog are your other soldiers on consoles.

If you're already playing on a console you can just set up a new account. The online pass seems to work in a per console manner (whether or not this was intended). This will only likely be beneficial on PS3 though since setting a new account up on Xbox Live will cost you.

> **[Source](http://bf3blog.com/2011/10/still-only-one-battlefield-3-soldier-per-origin-account/)**